# My link does not work despite loading URL package

Tags: urls, links

I wanted to insert the following link in my footnote (it works here below but not in my latex-compiled PDF):
https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/metadata/EN/migr_eil_esqrs_de.htm
Loaded in the preamble:
\usepackage{url}

```
\footnote{~For example, sometimes data are unavailable on third-country nationals who effectively returned to a third country (by type of return and citizenship) and third-country nationals who returned to a third country (by the destination country and citizenship). For this point, \textit{see}, e.g., \url{https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/metadata/EN/migr_eil_esqrs_de.htm}}
```

When I click on it, it navigates me to a page with the error "You don't have permission to access this resource."

Could anyone please advise on how to include the functioning URL?

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Required package
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
 \renewcommand{\&}{and}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords}} #1}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Doc}

\date{December 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
Little is known even today about emigration patterns, including knowledge of returnees' demographics (\textit{see} e.g., Borjas and Bratsberg, 1996; Constant and Massey, 2002). Return migration is difficult to measure, which is one of the main constraints. Research on recent returns or repeated migration from Germany is scarce. Return migration is a challenging research area and is sometimes not fully understood because of several data availability constraints impede analysis of the topic. For example, migrant outflow records might be undocumented (see e.g., \citeNP{Erlinghagen2016}). Despite the German register requiring the person to de-register when leaving the host country, this might not happen. Also, data on these outflows are sometimes missing.\footnote{~For example, the Enforcement of the Immigration Legislation metadata information ``EIL," which is collected by German Authorities in compliance with regulations on Community Statistics on Migration and International Protection, lacks information on outflows.} 

Data unavailability poses itself as one of the major challenges for analyzing return migration topics.\footnote{~For example, sometimes data are unavailable on third-country nationals who effectively returned to a third country (by type of return and citizenship) and third-country nationals who returned to a third country (by the destination country and citizenship). For this point, \textit{see}, e.g., \href{https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/metadata/EN/migr_eil_esqrs_de.htm}} This data unavailability exists despite member states' obligations to report the data sources used to Eurostat and provide the data to ensure statistical information completeness. All these reasons necessitate that both destination and source countries collect better data and statistics on return migration (\textit{see} Wahba, 2015). To fill part of this research gap and improve the information on return migration behaviors and magnitude, we examine whether the return has eventually materialized, which will be checked against declared return intentions in the empirical part of this paper. Nevertheless, several data limitations exist in answering this question for recent migrants, which we subsequently address in the limitations section. 

\end{document}
```

bib:

```
@Inbook{Erlinghagen2016,
author="Erlinghagen, Marcel",
editor="Tachibanaki, Toshiaki",
title="Anticipation of Life Satisfaction Before Emigration: Evidence from German Panel Data",
bookTitle="Advances in Happiness Research: A Comparative Perspective",
 year = {2016},
publisher="Springer Japan",
address="Tokyo",
pages="229--244",
isbn="978-4-431-55753-1",
doi="10.1007/978-4-431-55753-1_13",
url="https://doi.org/10.1007/978-4-431-55753-1_13   "
}
```

Comment: The `url` package is only meant to *format* URLs, not to include links. If you want to include a link, try the `\href` macro provided by the `hyperref` package.

Comment: You need the hyperref package for active links

Comment: Thank you! Can't I use URL as I have no description prior to the link? Can cleveref package be also in my preamble?

Comment: Also, \usepackage{hyperref} causes errors in my in-text citations (they appear without years), is there a way to use it only for the URL? And how should it be exactly written? Thank you.

Comment: If you load the `hyperref` package after all other packages, but *before* `apacite` and `cleveref`, the errors should be gone and you can just use `\url` which will provide a linked URL then.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much @JasperHabicht

Comment: On another note, 1. Is there a way to make all in text citations with more than two authors appear automatically in the text with (et. el.)? What I have now that sometimes more than two authors are mentioned with et el. while other times it lists the author's names. 2. To show authors' first names in full instead of their initials in the bibliography?